# Modify springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage xml before sending

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, soap

Valid SOAP request tested via SOAP UI:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="some_ns1_uri">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <ns0:Body>
        <ns1:AAA_method>
            <ns1:A>A</ns1:A>

            <ns1:B>B</ns1:B>

            <ns1:C>
                <ns1:string>C_string</ns1:string>
            </ns1:C>

            <ns1:D>
                <ns1:string>D_string</ns1:string>
            </ns1:D>

            <ns1:E>
                <ns1:val>E_val</ns1:val>
            </ns1:E>

            <ns1:F>
                <ns1:val>F_val</ns1:val>
            </ns1:F>
 
        </ns1:AAA_method>
    </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

`getResponseObj` method to send the message:

```
@Autowired
ClientConfig clientConfig;

@Autowired
Service service;
...
public ResponseObj getResponseObj() throws DatatypeConfigurationException {

        RequestObj request = service.buildRequest();
        WebServiceTemplate wst = clientConfig.webServiceTemplate();

        return (ResponseObj) wst.marshalSendAndReceive(request, new WebServiceMessageCallback() {

            @Override
            public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) throws IOException, TransformerException {
                SoapMessage soapMessage = ((SoapMessage) message);
                soapMessage.setSoapAction(soapActionHeader);

                soapMessage.writeTo(System.out); 
            }
        });
    }
```

`WebServiceTemplate` configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    @Value("${ws.username}") private String username;
    @Value("${ws.password}") private String usernamePassword;
    @Value("${ws.uri}") private String endpointUri;
    @Value("${ws.contextPath}") private String cxtPath;

    @Bean
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath(cxtPath); // package location where wsdl generated classes are
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    HttpClient httpClient() {

        List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        String userAndPassword = username + ":" + usernamePassword;
        BasicHeader authHeader = new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(userAndPassword.getBytes())));
        headers.add(authHeader);
        RequestDefaultHeaders reqHeader = new RequestDefaultHeaders(headers);

        return HttpClients.custom()
                .addInterceptorFirst(new HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor())
                .addInterceptorLast(reqHeader).build();
    }

    @Bean
    HttpComponentsMessageSender defaultMyMessageSender() {
        return new HttpComponentsMessageSender(httpClient());
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() {

        WebServiceTemplate wsTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
        wsTemplate.setDefaultUri(endpointUri);
        wsTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller());
        wsTemplate.setMessageSender(defaultMyMessageSender());

        return wsTemplate;
    }

}
```

Service has `buildRequest` method where I set the values and return `RequestObj`

The `writeTo` prints wrong SoapMessage, the message is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> // here missing 3 namespaces
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body> // wrong body tag name
        <ns2:RequestObj xmlns:ns2="some_ns1_uri"> // wrong tag name (ns2)
            <ns2:A>A</ns2:A>

            <ns2:B>B</ns2:B>

            <ns2:C>
                <ns2:string>C</ns2:string>
            </ns2:C>

            <ns2:D>
                <ns2:string>D</ns2:string>
            </ns2:D>

            <ns2:E>
                <ns2:val/> // missing E value
            </ns2:E>

            <ns2:F>
                <ns2:val/> // missing F value
            </ns2:F>
        </ns2:RequestObj>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

For missing envelope namespaces I've added the following to `doWithMessage`:

```
...
SoapEnvelope envelope = soapMessage.getEnvelope();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(nXsi, nXsiUri);
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(nNs0, nNs0Uri);
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(nNs1, nNs1Uri);
/*
Results:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="some_ns1_uri" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
*/
...
```

My question is how I could change:

- the body `SOAP-ENV:Body` to `ns0:Body`?
- the prefix `ns2` from Body element tags to `ns1`?

I'm using `org.springframework.ws.WebServiceMessage` and convering to `org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessage`.

I know the SOAPMessage API allows methods to `setPrefix` to change Body element tag prefixes and Body prefix too. But I need to use the `org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessage`.

My idea was to convert `message.getPayloadSource()` to `Document` and then Document convert it to `InputStream` to manually correct the XML and change it back to `org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessage` object to be able to send valid request. But I'm sure it's overkill...

To get back to main question - how can I modify the SoapMessage (content) to be valid to be sent?

All ideas are welcome

Update #1

When sending request (with and without fixing envelope headers it doesn't matter):

```
2021-01-04 10:24:49.091 ERROR 2032 --- [nio-7845-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 409). ---> System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.
   at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags kinds)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read2_ahs_date(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read11_RequestSeriesData()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()] with root cause

org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 409). ---> System.FormatException: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value.
   at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String text, XsdDateTimeFlags kinds)
   at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode dateTimeOption)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read2_e_value(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read11_RequestData()
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:830) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.10.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxxx.Client.getResponseObj(Client.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
    at xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.Controller.exampleTable(Controller.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:807) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1061) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

The `E` and `F` values are the `XMLGregorianCalendar` type dates and I'm using the `2021-01-05` formatted dates for it.

From wsdl file I see that `e_value` specified like this:

```
<s:complexType name="e_value">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="val" type="s:dateTime" />
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

So my guess the default `dateTime` formatter invokes this error?

Comment: The tag name shouldn't matter, nor where it is positioned as long as the declarations are there.

Comment: @M.Deinum are you sure or it's only "shouldn't matter" ? Because I'm not able to send the request. Could you share any sources?

Comment: In theory, it shouldn't matter, unless the receiving end is programmed in such a way that it expects this. But from an XML perspective, it shouldn't matter. Do you get an error when sending? If so please add that to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum added ```Update #1```

Comment: @M.Deinum Fixed date formatter problem it had ```2021-01-04T00:00:00``` format.. Now need to set unmarshaller and it should be alright. I'll add ```Update #2``` soon

Comment: So it is missing values not namespaces. Does the request have actual values for those fields?

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, now ```E``` and ```F``` fields has the values. ```getResponseObj() ... soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);``` prints the response with all values.

Comment: So it had nothing to do with namespaces but rather an invalid request being generated.

Comment: Hey, did you get any update on how to update the soap body?